# Java-TestNG : Read an excel file, assert and write back to the excel file through TestNG & Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, testng

I am working on a POC with Selenium Java and TestNG using Apache POI. I have an excel sheet in which Column A contains urls, Column B contains a status (yes or no) whether to read/execute with the corresponding url or not.I want to save back the execution status Pass/Fail in a Column C.

### My excel sheet "TestData.xlsx" [image: looks like this].

### My calling file "read_write_excel.java" is as follows:

```
package Read_Write_Excel;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import libraries.read_excel_data;
public class read_write_excel 
{

    String path = "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\excelData\\TestData.xlsx";
    @Test
    public void read_excel() throws Exception
    {
        read_excel_data excel = new read_excel_data(path);
        excel.read_data(0);
    }
}
```

### Reading the excel sheet through "read_excel_data.java" as follows:

```
package libraries;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class read_excel_data 
{

    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    String location;
    int SheetNo;
    write_excel_data write_excel;
    public read_excel_data(String excelPath)
        {
            location = excelPath;
            try {
                File src = new File(excelPath);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                write_excel = new write_excel_data(location);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }


    public void read_data(int sheetNumber) throws Exception
    {
        SheetNo = sheetNumber;
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
        int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println("Total number of Rows to read : "+(rows+1));
        for(int i=0;i<=rows;i++)
        {
            XSSFRow now_row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if(now_row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                String data = now_row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Data from Row "+i+" is: "+data);
                String status = assertion.asserting(data);
                System.out.println("Status is : "+status);
                write_excel.write_data(SheetNo,i,status);
            }
        }

        workbook.close();
    }

}
```

### Assertions are done in "assertion.java" like:

```
package libraries;
public class assertion 
{

    public static String asserting(String url)
    {
        String result;
        if(url.contains("com"))
            {
                result = "Pass";
                System.out.println("Result is : "+result);
                return result;
            }
        else
            {
                result = "Fail";
                System.out.println("Result is : "+result);
                return result;
            }

    }
}
```

### Writing back to the excel file through "write_excel_data.java" like:

```
package libraries;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class write_excel_data 
{

    File des;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    XSSFWorkbook wb;
    public write_excel_data(String location)
    {
        try {
            des = new File(location);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(des);
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void write_data(int sheetNo,int i, String status) throws Exception
    {
        sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNo);
        int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        System.out.println("Total number of Rows to write : "+(rows+1));
        sheet.getRow(i).createCell(2).setCellValue(status);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(des);
        wb.write(fos);
        wb.close();
    }
}
```

The issue I am facing are:

1. Sometimes I run into a NullPointerException
2. Sometime the Excel sheet gets corrupted and doesn't writes at all.

Can you please let me know:

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Any suggestion for betterment?
3. If I am doing any mistakes here.

---

Update -1:

Latest Stacktrace:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\DEDLY\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1619303069\testng-customsuite.xml

Total number of Rows to read : 3
Data from Row 0 is: a.com
Result is : Pass
Status is : Pass
Total number of Rows to write : 3
Data from Row 1 is: b.com
Result is : Pass
Status is : Pass
Total number of Rows to write : 3
[Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\DEDLY\workspace\SeleniumJavaTestNG\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
[Utils]   Directory C:\Users\DEDLY\workspace\SeleniumJavaTestNG\test-output\Default suite exists: true
FAILED: read_excel
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Rule M2.4 exception : this error should NEVER happen, if so please send a mail to the developers team, thanks !
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.getContentType(ContentTypeManager.java:342)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ContentTypeManager.removeContentType(ContentTypeManager.java:255)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.removePart(OPCPackage.java:943)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getOutputStream(PackagePart.java:522)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.commit(XSSFWorkbook.java:1546)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.onSave(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:332)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:195)
    at libraries.write_excel_data.write_data(write_excel_data.java:38)
    at libraries.read_excel_data.read_data(read_excel_data.java:51)
    at Read_Write_Excel.read_write_excel.read_excel(read_write_excel.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1137)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:753)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:607)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:368)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:363)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:321)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

---

Update - 2:

When I try to open the "TestData.xlsx" manually, I get the following error as [image: attached].

Comment: Please paste a stack trace from your null pointer exception.  Also when you don't have issue 1 or 2, does it work correctly as you expect?

Comment: @BillK Thanks, I have updated my Question with the latest stacktrace. Would you please have a look?

Comment: before wb.close(); try to use wb.flush();

Comment: @AnandGaneshSS Thanks. But Eclipse IDE shows an error as `The method flush() is undefined for the type XSSFWorkbook` while I try to add the line.

Comment: The file is opened twice at the same time. You should try to pass `XSSFWorkbook` in `write_excel_data` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your stack trace it looks like it might have something to do with cell types (the top-most calls are "removeContentType" and "getContentType".  I assume that this means it's trying to put a string in an int cell or perhaps a cell that doesn't exist.

Try putting text in each of the three cells in column C for a start.  If that works you might look through the API to see if there is a way to set the type for that cell.

If that doesn't work you could try to save your initial spreadsheet (from Excel) as an older type.  Sometimes Poi doesn't work as well with the newest excel versions.

I can't figure out where you are setting "des", have you omitted some code or did you forget to set it?  At any rate, try a different source/destination, don't overwrite (I can't tell if you are).

Also, since you asked for suggestions:

1. Java wants ALL packages (in the world) to be uniquely named, so instead of using "libraries" as a package, consider com.mycompany.project.libraries or something like that.
2. All your variables should always be private.  Just do that.  The only exception is "public final static" constants, and they should only reference immutable objects (int, String, ...)
3. Class names should be (for example) WriteExcelData instead of write_excel_data.  Although this is only a pattern, it is very consistently used in the community.